# using usb camera with opencv on android

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I am trying to use a UVC camera with opencv for real time detection, similar to the sample from http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-updated-for-opencv-2-4-6/.however, i found a problem that opencv need the CameraBridgeViewBase class to interact with camera.

i tried to use the setCameraIndex to set the UVC cam, but seems like i cannot find the camera index of uvc cam when i set the index to 0 and 1, the app work properly with front cam and back cam of my phone(galaxy S3)

i have tried other libraries (lately https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) to build connection with the cam then use opencv to process the frame but it never work as i cannot use the cam dirrectly without CameraBridgeViewBase

is there any way i can find the camera index of the uvc cam? or is there anyway to use it without CameraBridgeViewBase ?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392007/connect-android-phone-to-a-usb-web-camera

Answer (score -1):

You can get camera preview bitmap from saki4510t/UVCCamera，and then use opencv to do some work through this bitmap